# Problem with sending data from partent component to child component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a problem with sending data from parent to child. I want to send info about color and then use that color to change background by tailwind.

Parent component:

```
import PlanetInfo from "../components/PlanetInfo";
import data from "../data/data.json";

const HomePage = () => {
  const dataPlanet = data.find((data) => data.name.toLowerCase() === "mercury");
  const color = "#419EBB";

  return (
    <div>
      <PlanetInfo data={dataPlanet} colorContentactive={color} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

I am sending that to `PlanetInfo` and when I check `color` in this component by `console.log`, I get information about this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PlanetInfo = ({ data, colorContentactive }) => {
  const [planetContentActive, setPlanetContentActive] = useState("overview");

  let sourcePlanet;
  if (planetContentActive === "overview") sourcePlanet = data.images.planet;
  else if (planetContentActive === "structure")
    sourcePlanet = data.images.internal;
  else sourcePlanet = data.images.geology;

  const contentActive = `before:absolute  before:bottom-0 before:h-[4px] before:w-full before:bg-[${colorContentactive}]`;
  console.log(colorContentactive);
  return (
    <main>
      <div className=" border-b border-white/20 font-['spartan league'] tracking-[2px] font-bold text-[9px] h-[50px] flex uppercase text-white px-6 gap-11 justify-center items-center">
        <div
          onClick={() => setPlanetContentActive("overview")}
          className={`relative ${
            planetContentActive === "overview" ? contentActive : ""
          } cursor-pointer h-full flex justify-center items-center`}
        >
          <h3>overview</h3>
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={() => setPlanetContentActive("structure")}
          className={`relative
            ${
              planetContentActive === "structure" ? contentActive : ""
            } cursor-pointer h-full flex justify-center items-center`}
        >
          <h3>structure</h3>
        </div>

        <div
          onClick={() => setPlanetContentActive("surface")}
          className={`relative
            ${
              planetContentActive === "surface" ? contentActive : ""
            } +  cursor-pointer h-full flex justify-center items-center`}
        >
          <h3>surface</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className=" my-24">
        <img
          src={`.${sourcePlanet}`}
          className=" h-[111px] w-[111px] mx-auto"
        />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default PlanetInfo;
```

but then I use `color` in variable and it's not working
`` const contentActive = `before:absolute  before:bottom-0 before:h-[4px] before:w-full before:bg-[${colorContentactive}]`; ``

I want to create underline when button is active.
If I use f.ex. `style={{ backgroundColor: colorContentactive }}` it's working in this component, but I can't send this to class before.

Code in my opinion is ok, because it works if I manually put color in this before like `"before:bg-[#419EBB]"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the issue you're getting. But I'd rather use a generic props attribute in your child component.

```
const PlanetInfo = (props) => {
  const { data, colorContentActive } = props;
  const [activeColor, setActiveColor] = useState(colorContentActive); // Create a editable style, using the color given by props as default.
}
```

If you're using typing in your project, you can also include this in your function declaration. This increases your readability.

```
interface PlanetInfoProps {
  data: any;
  colorContentActive: string;
}

const PlanetInfo = (props: PlanetInfoProps) => {
  // ...
}
```

And for the underline, why not use `text-decoration` instead? You can just do `text-decoration: underline;` when hovering.

Comment: I want to do something like that https://pasteboard.co/UXm5bwQqI3Do.png

Comment: And when I write `before:absolute  before:bottom-0 before:h-[4px] before:w-full before:bg-[#419EBB}]`   it works, but when i want use props, i don't get anything.  In developer tools I see this before and it has width and height, but it still hidden

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repository of your project? I might be able to look into it better this way.

Comment: Yea, https://github.com/blazejpak/planets-fact-site/tree/test

Comment: It's in component folder

Comment: I'm unable to see your repository. Is it currently set to private?